# VIM with Python - Multiple # do not get colored as a comment

Tags: vim, python, vi, vimrc, syntax-highlighting

Something changed on my system and now VIM screws up syntax highlighting of commented lines.

This makes having 'debug' lines very difficult as it looks like the line is still active based on the coloring!

Behold:
[image: Screenshot of Improper VIM python comment highlighting]

In particular, look at the second print statement. From a quick glance at the color of that line, you'd think it wasn't commented out at all!

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Output of `vim -Nu NONE -c 'filetype on|set filetype=python|syntax on' hello_world.py` followed by `:scriptnames`

```
  1: /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
  2: /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftdetect/stp.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
  6: ~/.vim/syntax/python.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/python.vim
```

Comment: What plugins do you have installed? What happens if you run `vim -Nu NONE -c 'filetype on|set filetype=python|syntax on' hello_world.py`?

Comment: BTW, vim's default of dark-blue on black for comments can be unreadable.  try changing it to cyan instead with `hi Comment    term=bold ctermfg=DarkCyan guifg=Blue` in your ~/.vimrc

Comment: @muru, no change running the command you suggest.

Comment: Ok, still using that command, after starting, run `:scriptnames`, and add the list of files to your question.

Comment: Try removing your `~/.vim/syntax/python.vim` and load file again.

Comment: Yup! Removing my python.vim does it. I suppose I need to go line by line and figure out what is causes it?

Comment: I suppose I simply have an out of date python.vim file. Looking for a new one now.

Answer (score 1):

I think your file-type setting have gone some how wrong.
At least in my VIM, python is in minor letter.

what happen when you set the file type manually?

```
:setf python
```

Comment: No change it looks like.